# Problem with images in css files with rails 6 and webpacker

Tags: webpack, jquery-ui-datepicker, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I have want to understand how Webpacker works on Rails 6 but I am getting very frustrated because I can't find good documentation.

I am just getting started with webpack, but webpacker gem makes things too complicated on my opinion. After a lot of struggling I got bootstrap 4 working, but when I try to use jquery-ui-datepicker I have problems with static files referenced on css files. I have this error on my log:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png"):
```

I installed jquery-datepicker using yarn, the datepicker is working well, but the problem occurs when it tries to load the images.

Although it can work without the images, I want to know how can I make it behave properly.

I am this versions:

- Rails 6.0.0
- Ruby 2.6.5
- Webpacker Gem 4.0.7
- Webpack 4.32.2
- jquery-datepicker 1.12.3

This is my `config/webpack/environment.js`:

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

module.exports = environment
```

This is the fragment of code than loads jquery-datepicker

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import datepickerFactory from 'jquery-datepicker';
import datepickerJAFactory from 'jquery-datepicker/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-es';

// Just pass your jquery instance and you're done
datepickerFactory($);
datepickerJAFactory($);

$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Is that image in your app/assets directory? What about your CSS? If so, it would be helpful to see the directory layout and how you're importing those files.

Comment: How did you install the datepicker library? Where are you importing the CSS? Are there images in the datepicker node_modules folder?

Comment: Please post the contents of the CSS file you’re referring to.